# Work with mysql database in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel used this https://github.com/msurguy/laravel-facebook-login link to work with facebook login in Laravel. I have setup all the things but i 
got following errors when establishing database connection :

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Redis\Database::__construct() must be of the type array,
>   null given, called in
>   C:\wamp64\www\laravel-facebook-login-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider.php
>   on line 23

I want to run simple mysql database. Below is my database.php code:

```
return array(

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

   'connections' => array(



        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'facebookdb',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',
            'port'  => '3603',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        )
    ),


    'migrations' => 'migrations',

);
```

Any suggestion/help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you're new to Laravel, why are you learning from a tutorial based on 4.2? That version is 3.5 years old, it doesn't even get any long-term support, and a *lot* has changed since then. Why not use a tutorial based on the current version? I'd strongly recommend checking out [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/) (no affiliation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the definition for your `redis` connection in that `connections` array, something like this will help:

```
'redis' => array(
    'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 127.0.0.1),
    'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
    'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
    'database' => env('REDIS_DATABASE', 0)
)
```

Make sure that you add the corresponding entries in your `.env` file if your `redis connection settings` differ from the default values above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Environment file was missing so i have to recreate it.